# Angularfire2 firebase config in environment.ts or inside module?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

According to the official documentation for AngularFire2 they put the initial config inside environment.ts but everywhere else I've seen it placed in the app.component.module.ts file (or whatever module they're working in).

Which is correct?  If they're both correct, which one is preferred?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both will work, but it is recommended to use `environment.ts` because you can have multiple environments like one for development and one for production.

As you can see `environment.ts` is imported and configured in `app.module.ts`, and the default behavior is  `production: false`.

Now you can create another environment `environment.prod.ts` and change its settings to `production: true` with another firebase config.

then when you say `ng build` the default environment loads and with `ng build --prod` the production environment loads.

Environment commands are configured in `angular-cli.json` under

```
"environments": {
    "source": "environments/environment.ts",
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
```